# how to do pdf thumbnails in flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm developing a pdf app with flutter. The thing I want to say is how I should do with pdf's thumbnails. I mean when the users open the application the second time after installing, I want to show the screen of pdf's thumbnails instantly not loading again. How should I do? Save images locally or any solution?. The code is below.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:card_swiper/card_swiper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'constant.dart';
import 'file_picker.dart';
import 'icon_button.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:pdf_image_renderer/pdf_image_renderer.dart';
import 'package:path_provider_extention/path_provider_extention.dart';
import 'file_manager.dart';
import 'save_screen.dart';
import 'sorting.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
 }

 class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
    List<FileSystemEntity> pdffile;
    List<Uint8List> pdfimage = [];
    BannerAd bannerAds;
    AppOpenAd openAd;
    bool isAdsload = false;
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      initBannerAds();
      loadAd();
      getFile();
     }

    void dispose() {
      super.dispose();
      bannerAds.dispose;
    }

    loadAd() {
    AppOpenAd.load(
    adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-4233045876357680/8169845508',
    request: const AdRequest(),
    adLoadCallback: AppOpenAdLoadCallback(onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      print('ad is loaded');
      openAd = ad;
      openAd.show();
    }, onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
      print('ad failed to load $error');
    }),
    orientation: AppOpenAd.orientationPortrait);
   }

    initBannerAds() {
      bannerAds = BannerAd(
      size: AdSize.banner,
      adUnitId:'ca-app-pub-4233045876357680/9259518166',
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          setState(() {
          isAdsload = true;
        });
       },
       onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
         print(error.toString());
       },
      ),
      request: AdRequest(),
      );
     bannerAds.load();
     }

     getFile() async {

       await Permission.storage.request();
       List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
       var root = storageInfo[0].rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, geting the root 
                 // directory
       var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
        pdffile = await fm.filesTree(
       excludedPaths: [
         "/storage/emulated/0/Android"
        ],
       extensions: [
         "pdf",
        ],
       sortedBy: FlutterFileUtilsSorting.Alpha,
      //optional, to filter files, list only pdf files
        );
       print(pdffile);


       for (int index = 0; index < pdffile.length; index++) {
           final document = await PdfImageRendererPdf(path: pdffile[index].path);
           await document.open();

          // open a page from the pdf document using the page index
          await document.openPage(pageIndex: 0);

         // get the render size after the page is loaded
           final size = await document.getPageSize(pageIndex: 0);

        // get the actual image of the page
          final pageImage = await document.renderPage(
             pageIndex: 0,
              x: 0,
             y: 0,
             width: size.width,
          // you can pass a custom size here to crop the image
             height: size.height,
         // you can pass a custom size here to crop the image
             scale: 1,
         // increase the scale for better quality (e.g. for zooming)
            background: Colors.white,
           );
          await document.closePage(pageIndex: 0);
           document.close();


           setState(() {
             pdfimage.add(pageImage);
              });

           print(pdfimage);
           }
           }

              @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return SafeArea(
             child: Scaffold(
            drawer: Drawer(
               child: ListView(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
               children: [
             DrawerHeader(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan), child: Text("Jensen 
               Pdf Viewer", style: fontStyle)),
            ListTile(
                leading: iconButton(icons: Icons.folder_open, onPress: () {}),
                title: Text('Pick Files', style: styles),
                onTap: () {
                  FilePickers().PickFile();
                }),
            ListTile(
                leading: iconButton(icons: Icons.bug_report, onPress: () {}),
                title: Text('Report Bug', style: styles),
                onTap: () async {
                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                    Get.toNamed('fourth');
                  });
                })
          ],
        )),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Jensen Pdf Viewer', style: fontStyle),
    ),
    body: pdfimage != null
        ? Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, right: 3),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFA9C9CC),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        spreadRadius: 5,
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: Offset(4, 3), // changes position of shadow
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
                    )),
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    child: Swiper(
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return InkWell(
                            onTap: () async {
                              await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                                Get.toNamed('second', arguments: '${pdffile[index].path}');
                              });
                            },
                            child: Card(
                              elevation: 20,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(image: MemoryImage(pdfimage[index]), fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                      itemCount: pdfimage.length,
                      itemWidth: 250.0,
                      layout: SwiperLayout.STACK,
                    ))),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Container(
            child: Text("Categories", style: fontStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: pdfimage.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  String fileName = pdffile[index].path.split('/').last;
                  return Card(
                      color: context.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                      elevation: 10,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                                    Get.toNamed('second', arguments: '${pdffile[index].path}');
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                                      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.21,
                                    ),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      boxShadow: [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                          spreadRadius: 2,
                                          blurRadius: 7,
                                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                      image: DecorationImage(image: MemoryImage(pdfimage[index]), fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                    ))),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Center(
                              child: Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                  child: Text(
                                    fileName,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: styles,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            iconButton(
                                icons: Icons.forward,
                                onPress: () async {
                                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                                    Get.toNamed('second', arguments: '${pdffile[index].path}');
                                  });
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ));
                  //  }))
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
        : Container(child: Center(child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(20), child: Text("There is no Pdf in Internal Storage. Tap Menu Icon", style: fontStyle)))),
    bottomNavigationBar: isAdsload
        ? Container(
      width: bannerAds.size.width.toDouble(),
      height: bannerAds.size.height.toDouble(),
      child: AdWidget(
        ad: bannerAds,
      ),
    )
        : null,
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: So you mean Let it be.  I think making the users wait is a bad experience. Don't know how to do it wew.

Comment: My app only reads pdf files from internal storage (phone storage). However, thank you for your suggestion man.

Comment: Can you tell me which package you used to create the  thumbnail for pdf. @Alex Jenson

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a package to show thumbnails for PDF files.

[pdf_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_thumbnail)

You can simply use it as a widget.

```
PdfThumbnail.fromFile(pdfFile)
```

[image: https://media.giphy.com/media/D58yM6RFV1AOxV8Y86/giphy.gif]